# How to ORDER before GROUP with DBIx::Class

Tags: sql, perl, group-by, sql-order-by, dbix-class

I've got a simple temporal table that looks like this:

```
Table: item_approval

item  user  status         modified
2     fred  approved       2010-12-01 00:00:00
3     fred  approved       2010-12-02 00:00:00
4     fred  disapproved    2010-12-03 00:00:00
7     jack  unapproved     2010-12-05 00:00:00
4     fred  approved       2010-12-06 00:00:00
4     jack  unapproved     2010-12-07 00:00:00
4     fred  disapproved    2010-12-04 00:00:00
```

I'm using DBIx::Class.  My "Item" result is defined with:

```
__PACKAGE__->has_many(
  "item_approvals",
  "Schema::Result::ItemApproval",
  { "foreign.item" => "self.id" },
  { cascade_copy => 0, cascade_delete => 0 },
);
```

Which means I can do:

```
my $item = $schema->resultset('Item')->find({id=>4});
```

Which is fine.  Then, I can do:

```
my @approvals = $item->item_approvals;
```

to get a resultset like this:

```
item  user  status         modified
4     fred  disapproved    2010-12-03 00:00:00
4     fred  approved       2010-12-06 00:00:00
4     jack  unapproved     2010-12-07 00:00:00
4     fred  disapproved    2010-12-04 00:00:00
```

My question:  How do I get the set of Fred and Jack's single most recent approval status?  That is, I want to get this resultset:

```
item  user  status         modified
4     fred  approved       2010-12-06 00:00:00
4     jack  unapproved     2010-12-07 00:00:00
```

I tried things like this:

```
my @approvals = $item->search({}, {
    group_by => 'user',
    order_by => {-desc => 'modified'}
});
```

but the "ORDER BY" is executed *after* the "GROUP BY", so I get things like this instead:

```
item  user  status         modified
4     fred  disapproved    2010-12-03 00:00:00
4     jack  unapproved     2010-12-07 00:00:00
```

Help?

Comment: I don't know perl or dbix, but the SQL way of doing this would be to make your `modified` field a `MAX(modified) as 'Modified'` which would return the highest date per user.

Comment: I've played with this a bit, using things like: SELECT item, user, status, MAX(modified) as most_recent FROM item_approval WHERE id=4;  but it doesn't return the highest date *per user*; it just returns the single row with the highest date.

Comment: you need to do both a `MAX(Modified)` AND `GROUP BY User`.  The `MAX` without a `GROUP` gives you the max for the query.  The `GROUP BY` gives you the max (or other aggregate functions like `SUM`, `AVG`, etc) for each group in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I changed it to [SELECT item, user, status, MAX( modified ) as modified FROM item_approval me WHERE ( me.item = 4 ) GROUP BY user] but that had the bizzare effect of giving only the max *modified*, not the row with the max modified.  That is, it gave me the first row, but with the wrong "modified" value (the modified value of the row with the max modified for that user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the behavior described in your comments I'm guessing your database is MySQL. 
I'm also assuming your `item_approval` table has a primary key which I will call `PK`.

One option is to use a sub select to pick the row that has the largest (most recent) `modified` value:

```
select item, user, status, modified 
from item_approval me 
where PK = (select s.PK from item_approval s where me.item = s.item and me.user = s.user order by s.modified desc, s.PK desc limit 1) 
and me.item = 4
```

This is a fairly slow option because it will re-run the sub select for each row and then reject all but one row for each item/user combination.
Other databases have slightly different ways to get similar results.